# Why does the yarn command report an error when executing my script

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const root = __dirname;

function createSpawn(command, next) {
    const child = spawn(command, {
        stdio: 'inherit',
        shell: true,
        cwd: root,
    });
    child.on('exit', function () {
        if (typeof next === 'function') {
            next();
        }
    });
}

function install() {
    fs.rmSync(path.resolve(root, '.husky'), {
        recursive: true,
        force: true,
    });
    createSpawn('npx husky install', () => {
        createSpawn('npx husky add .husky/pre-commit "npm run pre-commit"', () => {
            createSpawn('npx husky add .husky/commit-msg "npx --no -- commitlint --edit #EE#"', () => {
                const file = path.resolve(root, '.husky/commit-msg');
                let content = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
                content = content.replace('#EE#', '"$1"');
                fs.writeFileSync(file, content);
            });
        });
    });
}

install();
```

I test on windows, and it work fine

I used the yarn command to install dependencies, but an error occurred. It was still good before. I suspect that the permissions of the husky file are incorrect, but an error is reported in the yarn script

but when i use the commnad `node install.js` it work fine!!!

here is the error

yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ node install.js

node:internal/fs/utils:344
throw err;
^

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ao/Desktop/Yeastar/PPV3/ppfe/.husky/commit-msg'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at /Users/ao/Desktop/Yeastar/PPV3/ppfe/install.js:32:34
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ao/Desktop/Yeastar/PPV3/ppfe/install.js:17:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/ao/Desktop/Yeastar/PPV3/ppfe/.husky/commit-msg'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: looks like the file `/Users/ao/Desktop/Yeastar/PPV3/ppfe/.husky/commit-msg` doesn't exist

Comment: yeah, but the command command npx husky install touch the file in the child-process

Comment: so, you've confirmed that file does exist?

Comment: Yes, but the command createSpawn ('npx husky install ') creates the file after execution, which makes me confused